# Will the charge flow to another capacitor after the switch is opened or will stay on $12 \rm F$ capacitor as there is no potential difference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

[image]

This is a question from a test series for iit jee.

- answer of the question is zero

Comment: Is the title of your post your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the title of your post is your question. Please note that we can not provide solutions to homework and exercise type questions, only offer guidance. Here is some guidance:

1. In a dc circuit under steady state conditions ideal capacitors look like open circuits unless shorted (as by switch S) and
2. immediately after a switching event the voltages on all capacitors is the same as they were immediately before the switching event (you can't change the voltage across an ideal capacitor instantaneously).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So that means the whole potential drop across the battery is on the 12F capacitor.

Comment: @user695268 Exactly. Now do you see why the answer is zero?